# How can I log an HTTP POST response in React Native app?

Tags: post, logging, react-native, fetch

I have a simple React Native app with a button. On press, it calls the following function which makes a POST request.
I have tested in POSTMAN and the request works. However, I want to test my app and I'm unable to log the response or any errors. Only the console.log statements for 'here' and 'done' are being printed (I see them in Chrome using remote debugger).

It seems like the fetch function is just being ignored, no warning/errors/logs.
What am I doing wrong here? Or what's the best way to make sure the Request is working?

```
_onPressButton() {
  console.log('here');
  fetch('http://passport.local/oauth/token', {  
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: '2',
      client_secret: 'value',
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: 'value',
      password: 'value',
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.warn(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(responseJson);
    return responseJson;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  console.log('done');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the virtual host wasn't being resolved. I used ngrok to tunnel the address "passport.local" into an ngrok URL and it worked.